# Upload to server via web interface

Tags: server, files, webserver

I am running a mediawiki on Ubuntu Server 14.04 via parallels with OS X as host.  I am looking for a way to upload files via a web interface to the server's drive and for any location.  It is ok if feature is part of a larger package.

I am NOT worried about securing the server.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is best solution [Owncloud](https://owncloud.com/).

You can upload, download files from any location using web browser.
Also you can create users ...

Manual for instalation is [here](http://sharadchhetri.com/2015/04/26/install-owncloud-8-on-ubuntu-server-14-04/)

Owncloud is well documented and if you wish you can use owncloud cilent ...

Admini guide is [here](https://doc.owncloud.org/server/8.0/admin_manual/contents.html)